# starting/stopping spring boot embedded tomcat project at boot and remotely

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, debian

What is the best practice of running a Spring Boot project with embedded Tomcat on a prod server so that it boots up with the machine and to have a way of kill and start the application remotely (For Jenkins deployments)?